# What are the minimal permissions to read git repo policies using {projectName}/_apis/git/policy/configurations api

Tags: azure-devops

Looking to READ (not modify) policies across a variety of projects/repositories/refnames (all elements that are query parameters to the call). However I am getting back empty result sets, even for repositories/branches I *know* have policies.... Using a test environment of my own (where I am Full Administrator) I get the expected results..

So what are the minimum permissions I must request to the production environments to harvest this information???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the results of my test, you need to set Project Settings => Repositories =>Policies =>Reserved names to on.

[image]

Then when you create Personal Access Tokens, you need to check the Read option of Code at least to get the correct response name "200 OK" and the complete result.

[image]

In addition, the user needs to have the reader permission of the project.

Comment: My PAT has "Full" permissions... Setting a policy about names that are allowed in a repository makes no sense (to me).... To be clear, I am using:

{projectName}/_apis/git/policy/configurations

However it returns 0 when applied to customer environment (all other calls work fine)...yet works perfectly with my (where I am an administrator).  A quick test under client's eye shows that if I am granted PRojhect Administerator then it works (but that is not sustainable)....so what is the minimal PERMISSION???

Comment: When I test, as long as the user has the project reader permission and performs the above operation, I can get the correct result in postman. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I will try again. If there are new discoveries, I will tell you.

Comment: After much round and round, the environment was deleted and re-created. The permission assignments were insane, and there were denies in various locations.